# Javascript to display CGI output on same page

Tags: javascript, php, cgi

I'm trying to display a form action on same page. Right now it is redirecting to CGI output. How can I display output on the same page without moving away.

Below is the form configured in the page.

```
<h1>How fast is your connection?</h1>

<hr>

<FORM METHOD=get

ACTION="http://getmeip.net/cgi-bin/1.cgi">

Look for?

<input type=string name=ping>

<P>

<input type=submit value="ping this host">

</form>

</HTML>
```

[Output is redirecting as shown in this picture. .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSVHc.png)

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1. Edit the CGI program so it outputs the HTML for the form *or*
2. Use JavaScript with [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) or `fetch` to get the data instead of submitting the form and then [update the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) of the existing page with the response